# C datatypes size after compilation

Tags: c, assembly, compilation, low-level

The question is as follows: does the C programming language define how the executables produced by compilers should be formatted in terms of data size types? To better explain this, let's assume I compile a C source code file that contains a variable of type int called 'x'. I successfully compile the source code into an executable and run it. During runtime the memory location allocated for 'x' is 4 bytes wide and structured under 2's complement standard.

If I were to run the same compiled executable from a different machine with the same operating system and a compatible CPU, do I have any guarantee that the variable will at all times be 4 bytes wide in the exact same format (meaning the exact same bit footprint)? I know that C has variable data sizes for elementary types and that this only applies to pre-compiled code. But what about post-compiled code? If int translates to assembler DWORD data type on one machine that allocates 32 bits to it, is there any guarantee it will take the form of 32 bits on another? Is DWORD always the same across different CPUs of the same model?

I've always assumed that compilation is just the process of establishing all implementation details and 'setting in stone' the exact size and internal formats of data types in-memory but I would like some confirmation. Also, does this apply to C++ as well?

Comment: It is the C **source code** which should be portable.

Comment: Just by using different compilation flags on the same compiler on the same machine you can get different types.

Comment: Do you mean actual compilation here or are you open to "psych! I targeted a VM so nothing is really settled yet"

Comment: Let's assume the simplest scenario and just say regular compilation on a target architecture

Comment: This is actually a really interesting question ... much more complex than it first appears.

Comment: why do you care? There can be subtle gradations of answer

Comment: @Alex> I don't understand from your question: do you mean 1) taking the compiled binary and running it on another similar system, or 2) compiling the program again on another similar system?

Comment: No recompilation involved. You compile it once and "share" the exact same executable across different machines

Comment: and to answer pm100, if he directed the question at me, this was for mere academic curiosity purely of how low level executables are formatted

Comment: @Alex shouldn't you rather ask this as a machine code/executable format question then, and leave all the vagueries of C and other high level languages behind?

Comment: @Alex> if you're running a linux of some sort, check out [ELF file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) first, then play with `objdump -d` on a small binary of yours, you'll get a better understanding of how pieces fit together. Try to compile with and without optimization as well, and see what you recognize in the generated binary.

Comment: Because the main curiosity came from how such vagueries are resolved in more detail. I picked C because it has variable-sized data types and I wanted to see if this somehow impacted post-compilation code as well although I guess I have my answer now.

Comment: @WeatherVane A lot of code has no motivation to be particularly portable (particularly across the Windows/POSIX split). C was designed to support both portable *and* nonportable code.

Comment: You're getting downvoted a bunch, but if it's any comfort, I think that you had a good question.

Comment: Take also into consideration that some platforms and tools allow the compiler to produce multi-target binaries, which are done in a way, where single executable (package) contains different machine code for different target platforms. In such case the bit-size/order is fixed by compilation only when the same machine code is used on the other computer (usually the same CPU will be handled by the same machine code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below the C level, compilers also abide by some "application binary interface" (abbreviated ABI; not to mistake with API). This is what sets these details in stone. The application binary interface defines the size of types and the representation of integers, among a *lot* of other things, like how parameters are passed to functions.

A single platform can support multiple ABIs. For instance, on Windows, you have the native ABI, and you can install Cygwin, which lets you run programs with an ABI closer to the Linux one. However, assuming that two different machines have support for the same ABI, then yes, sharing executables between them is guaranteed to work (assuming the required libraries and such are present) and everything is guaranteed to have a compatible representation.

This is the same in principle for C++.

Comment: Note the OP's question was about the size of data types (or so I read it), not about the ABI.

Comment: @NeilButterworth, the size of data types is dictated by the ABI. Pointer size, whether `long` is 32 or 64 bits (on modern machines), negative representation, padding between struct fields are all ABI questions.

Comment: "Please tell me: if the ABI doesn't define the size of types, then what does? "   - partially the C Standard ( you can't have longs with sizeof(1)), partially the documentation for your compiler.

Comment: Hmm, even if you can't have `sizeof(long)==1`, you don't know how many bytes `sizeof(x)==1` means either. Anyway, that's not defining the sizes, but placing constraints on how they are allowed to be defined.

Comment: Just because the C standard doesn't specify or require the existence of an ABI does not, in fact, make things like the [x86_64 System V ABI specification](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/article/402129/mpx-linux64-abi.pdf) disappear. Why don't you bring it up to them that they chose the wrong name?

Answer (score 1):

> If I were to run the same compiled executable from a different machine with the same operating system and a compatible CPU, do I have any guarantee that the variable will at all times be 4 bytes wide in the exact same format

The C standard doesn't guarantee it, but it will be. This will be determined by the compiled machine code.

Comment: good answer - but I am tempted to ask 'why do you care?'. I suspect there is a more subtle ask underneath (I smell serialization)

Answer (score 1):

In various places, the C standard requires that any information that is available at compile-time must be "as-if" constant across all possible execution environments. This includes at least:

- the sizes and alignments of all types (`sizeof` and `_Alignof`, although there are ways to get alignment without the latter)
- the value ranges of arithmetic types, since they are accessible via `#include <limits.h>` and `#include <float.h>`.
- If the value ranges and sizes constrain it, the internal layout (which complement format for negative numbers, and the absence of padding bits/trap representations). For example, if `SCHAR_MIN` is -128 (it is only required to be <= -127) and `CHAR_BIT` is 8, then you are guaranteed 2's complement 8-bit `signed char`.

There are plenty of things that *can* vary (either just theoretically, or even practically) based on runtime system, though.